# How to retrieve JSON using retrofit with headers?

Tags: android, json, http, jackson, retrofit

Situation: I have an API token and want to get json data. But that token has to be used as header,not as query parametr. As I've understood I couldn't type on my browser request with header. For more information about API that I use,you can look there: https://developer.fantasydata.com/docs/services/594407b00f14bf15264fd958/operations/5944088b14338d0eb80b2809

Problem: Because of I do not know what kind of fields does JSON request have ,I cannot create a class for that json data. I want to use JacksonConverter. So the question is: how to get that JSON and look how it looks like,then create a class for that in order to convert?

Below you can see my code with understandable comments:

My PrefsApplication class for creating http request:

```
public class PrefsApplication extends Application {
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    static String base = "https://api.fantasydata.net/v3/soccer/scores/"; // my base url

    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        if(retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(base).addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create()).build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

My interface for doing get request and putting header

```
public interface RestInterface {
    @Headers("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: {MY_KEY}") // here is header, I don't know is it properly written?
    @GET("scores/json/Areas") // my get request
    Call<List<Country>> getCountries(); // here, I want to get list of countries
}
```

There is MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RestInterface rest = PrefsApplication.getClient().create(RestInterface.class);

        Call<List<Country>>call = rest.getCountries();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Country>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Country>> call, Response<List<Country>> response) { }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Country>> call, Throwable t) { }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: "Because of I do not know what kind of fields does JSON request have" -- consider using a service that has better documentation. Otherwise, use the `curl` command shown on that page to get sample output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an `interceptor` to your Retrofit `HttpClient` instance. This way you can setup custom headers.

A quick example is:

```
private static final String API_URL = "URL"; // Override with the service URL
private static final String YOUR_KEY = "KEY"; // Override with your key from the service

private static Retrofit.Builder retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(API_URL);
private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

public static RestInterface endpoint() {
    httpClient.interceptors().clear();

    httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request original = chain.request();

            Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                    .header("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", YOUR_KEY)
                    .method(original.method(), original.body());

            Request request = requestBuilder.build();
            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    });

    return retrofit.client(httpClient.build()).build().create(RestInterface.class);
}

// Then call to use a Retrofit instance with the headers
PrefsApplication.endpoint().getCountries();
```

This is used in all sorts of ways, like adding authentication. You can read more about it in [this complete guide](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/android-basic-authentication-with-retrofit) for Retrofit

This example is for Retrofit 2+ so be sure to add `compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'` to your dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a browser extension and make the http request with a custom header. [I prefer postman for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop)